# docker run -w giving unexpected error when run from go script

Tags: docker, go

I'm writing a very simple script that just formats a build command via docker for go apps. It formats the command like this:

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Users/me/go/src/goapp:/go/src/goapp -w /go/src/goapp -e GOOS=os -e GOARCH=arch image go build -v -o outputname
```

When running this, however I get the following:

> docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory ' /go/src/goapp' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path

I tried reformatting it like this:

```
docker run --rm -v="c:/Users/me/go/src/goapp:/go/src/goapp" -w="/go/src/goapp" -e="GOOS=os" -e"GOARCH=arch" image go build -v -o outputname
```

and get the same error, only the "invalid" working directory is `"/go/src/goapp"`

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func constructCmd(volumeMap, workingDir, goos, goarch, output, image string) []string {
    finalCmd := append([]string{"run", "--rm"},
        fmt.Sprintf("-v='%s'", volumeMap),
        fmt.Sprintf("-w='%s'", workingDir),
        fmt.Sprintf("-e='%s'", goos),
        fmt.Sprintf("-e='%s'", goarch),
    )

    finalCmd = append(finalCmd, image, "go build -v")

    if output != "" {
        finalCmd = append(finalCmd, fmt.Sprintf("-o %s", output))
    }

    return finalCmd
}

func main() {
    // Parse flags
    osPtr := flag.String("os", "windows", "Target distribution")
    archPtr := flag.String("arch", "amd64", "Target distribution")
    outputPtr := flag.String("out", "", "Output file name")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Printf("Building for %s/%s:\n", *osPtr, *archPtr)

    goos := "GOOS=" + *osPtr
    goarch := "GOARCH=" + *archPtr

    pwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        pwd = strings.Replace(pwd, "C", "c", 1)
        pwd = strings.Replace(pwd, "\\", "/", -1)
    }
    workingDir := pwd[strings.Index(pwd, "/go"):]
    volumeMap := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", pwd, workingDir)

    var image string
    if len(flag.Args()) == 0 {
        image = "golang"
    } else {
        image = flag.Args()[0]
    }

    execCmd := constructCmd(volumeMap, workingDir, goos, goarch, *outputPtr, image)

    cmd := exec.Command("docker", execCmd...)
    cmdOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
    cmd.Stdout = cmdOutput
    cmd.Stderr = cmdOutput
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        os.Stderr.WriteString(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Print(string(cmdOutput.Bytes()))
}
```

To note, if I run this command directly, it works no problem. No error. So this isn't a docker problem, it's a go problem. What could cause this error?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Can you try `--workdir="/go/src/goapp" `

Comment: You’re not passing arguments to a shell, don’t add unessecary quotes.

Comment: @JimB Ironically, the final solution that made this script work involved adding more quotes... only in the go script instead of the command haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quoted quotes.  As stated in [the exec package's documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/), Go's standard lib os/exec package does not invoke the shell to execute a Cmd:

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions, pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells. The package behaves more like C's "exec" family of functions.

Unless you're calling the shell in your command, there's no shell being invoked to process and remove those quotes.

For example, this:

```
"-v='%s'"
```

Should be this:

```
"-v=%s"
```

---

Update from comments: OP also found and fixed a second issue:

```
"go build -v"
```

needed to be split up into separate arguments:

```
"go", "build", "-v"
```

Comment: Doing this turns the error into `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"go build -v\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

Comment: @JaimeWissner If you haven't done this already: right before `cmd.Run()`, try calling fmt.Printf("%v\n", cmd.Args)` and make sure every arg looks looks right and there are no escapes or quotes that shouldn't be there

Comment: Printed it, and the command looks perfect. No escapes or quotes, and if I copy and run the command, it runs fine.

Comment: @JaimeWissner Did you make any other changes besides removing the single quotes? Could you give an example of how you're calling the Go script on the command line? If there's much new info/code, you could either call this question done on the quotes and start a new one, or update your question with the new info.

Comment: @JaimeWissner The error you reported comes out of `runc`: https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/master/libcontainer/container_linux.go , but I doubt that really helps you -- probably still a quote/escape/parse issue somewhere

Comment: Actually, I just found the answer to that part of it. The trick was taking the error literally. I told it run "go build -v", and it, indeed, tried to run "go build -v". When it couldn't find a binary called "go build -v", it shot out that error. Changing my command to be "go", "build", "-v" made it work.

Comment: @JaimeWissner glad you got it working - I'll update my answer with that note, or you can put it in an update/edit/solution section of your question